# Seeing unexpected "undefined" in strings served by Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just created a very simple web server with Node JS which asks for the name of a JSON file, then loops through it and serves up certain keys within it as a "formatted" text-file.

**CODE:**

```
var http = require('http'),
prompt = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

prompt.question("Which library? ", function (whichlib) {
    "use strict"
    var lib = require("./bot-client/lib/" + whichlib),
        rules = lib.data.ruleset,
        parse = function (ruleset, prefix) {
            var key,
                str;
            for (key in ruleset) {
                str += prefix + " -  " + key + "\n";
                str += (ruleset[key].hasOwnProperty("ruleset"))
                    ? parse(ruleset[key].ruleset, prefix + "\t")
                    : "";
            }
            return str;
        },
        str = parse(rules, "");
    console.log("Ready to serve page.");
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write(str);
        res.end();
    }).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
});
```

**EXAMPLE OF EXPECTED RESULT**:

```
 -  key1
     -  key1.1
         -  key1.1.1
         -  key1.1.2
     -  key1.2
         -  key1.2.1
         -  key1.2.2
         -  key1.2.3
     -  key1.3
         -  key1.3.1
         -  key1.3.2
```

**EXAMPLE OF ACTUAL RESULT**:

```
undefined -  key1
undefined    -  key1.1
undefined        -  key1.1.1
         -  key1.1.2
     -  key1.2
undefined        -  key1.2.1
         -  key1.2.2
         -  key1.2.3
     -  key1.3
undefined        -  key1.3.1
         -  key1.3.2
```

**QUESTION:**

I can't see why "undefined" should show up at all, much less see a pattern to its appearance. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: *slaps head* Indeed I am missing something obvious. D'oh! (It's been a long week...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You concatenate strings to a variable which is still `undefined`:

```
 var key,
     str; //you don't set any value here
     for (key in ruleset) {
         str += prefix + " -  " + key + "\n";
```

In the fourth line, `str` is still uninitialized. You can fix it by setting it to an empty string:

```
var key,
    str = '';
    for (key in ruleset) {
        str += prefix + " -  " + key + "\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you are missing the initialization of `str` and `key`.

In JavaScript, if you concat an undefined variable as a string it will literally say `undefined`.

In your case, change this:

```
        var key,
            str;
```

To this:

```
        var key = '',
            str = '';
```

To have the variables initialized.